# How to check if Dark Appearance is enabled tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, tvos10

How do I check if a user has enabled Dark Appearance on their Apple TV?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [UIUserInterfaceStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiuserinterfacestyle), first available in tvOS 10, we can check what appearance the user has set.

For example:

```
func checkInterfaceStyle() {
    guard(traitCollection.responds(to: #selector(getter: UITraitCollection.userInterfaceStyle)))
        else { return }

    let style = traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle

    switch style {
    case .light:
        print("light")
    case .dark:
        print("dark")
    case .unspecified:
        print("unspecified")
    }
}
```

Also, if you're updating from an Xcode 7/tvOS 9.0 project you will need to include `UIUserInterfaceStyle` in your `info.plist`. New projects created with Xcode 8 already have this key included.

[image]

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Automatic</string>
```

Comment: I tried this coding 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions', But it always shows 'unspecified'.

Comment: @Anas that might be too early to check. Try moving it into your first VC's `viewDidLoad`. Make sure you have the key included in your info.plist also.

Comment: @AlizainPrasla I'm sure that wouldn't be possible without using a private API as its a system wide setting.

Comment: Lovely. UIUserInterfaceStyle was what was missing on the info.plist file of Kingfisher demo. I just added it (and assigned the info.plist target to the tvOS app) and now it starts in dark mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this extension in Swift 5:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var isDarkModeEnabled : Bool {
        get {
            return traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call this in your UIViewControllers:

```
if self.isDarkModeEnabled {
    //Do something dark
} else {
    //Do something light
}
```