# How can I get the appearance style has been set on apple tv settings?

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

First of all, I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562862/how-to-check-if-dark-appearance-is-enabled-tvos) in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. It always return **unspecified** in my apple tv simulator. Is there have any other solution to check which appearance style has been set on apple tv settings?

I want to change my tvOS app's theme respect to dark or light appearance style.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check current style in [traitCollectionDidChange](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitraitenvironment/1623516-traitcollectiondidchange) and update UI there.

From Apple documentation

> Implement this method in view controllers and views, according to your app’s needs, to respond to such changes.

Sample usage

```
class DetailsHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private(set) var title: UILabel!

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)

        title.layer.borderColor = 
            traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? 
        UIColor.white.cgColor : UIColor.black.cgColor
    }    
}
```

Comment: how I implement "traitCollectionDidChange" in swift3 programming. Can you please give a sample code?.

Comment: Sounds like `traitCollectionDidChange` would only be called if the user changed the appearance when using the application. You can check the appearance style with `UIUserInterfaceStyle`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39562883/2108547